# lambda expression being rejected (C++11)

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, functor, overloading

```
virtual Answer<const Taaal& const> askWho(bool(const Taaal& const)) = 0;
virtual Answer<const Taaal& const> askWho(const Taaal& const t) {
    return askWho([&](auto q) {
        return q == t;
    });
}
```

is being rejected with "no instance of overloaded function matches the argument list" (additionally, I'm being told auto is not allowed, but replacing that with an explicit type leaves the first problem)

Taaal is the (abstract) class that these methods are declared in. Answer is #included from another header, and its definition shouldn't matter.

Comment: How is the function pointer supposed to store the lambda's state? Hint: It can't.

Comment: `auto` parameters in lambdas will be available in C++14, not in C++11.

Comment: changing auto to `const Taaal& const` still leaves the first problem, so I wrote it this way in my post for brevity.

Comment: @chris: You almost always answer questions in comments. Why don't you write an answer and get upvote from me?

Comment: @Nawaz, If it was an answer, I would feel compelled to spend time fleshing it all out more than necessary instead of going to sleep :/

Comment: What compiler are you using? You're not allowed to const qualify reference types. You should remove the second `const` from all parameter types in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only a capture-less lambda defines an implicit conversion to a function pointer. Your lambda expression captures its context because of the capture default `&`. Since your lambda cannot be stateless, you could change the parameter type of the other overload

```
virtual Answer<const Taaal&> askWho(std::function<bool(const Taaal&)>) = 0;
```

---

If your lambda didn't need to capture context variables, you could've dropped the `&` from the capture list and the conversion would've worked as expected

```
virtual Answer<const Taaal&> askWho(const Taaal& t) {
    return askWho([](auto q) {
//                ^^ - nothing here
        return ...;
    });
}
```

Note that the `auto q` parameter type for the lambda only works if you compile your code in C++14 mode (`-std=c++1y` on gcc and clang). In C++11 mode you'll have specify the parameter type.

Answer (score 0):

auto in lambdas is only allowed in C++14.

You must use the real parameter type, polymorphic lambdas are not included in C++11.